# Python ROT24 on string

Tags: python

I'm trying to do ROT24 on a string.

So as an example this code "{JgkJqPå}" should become "{HeiHoNå}".

I've managed to find out what character in the alpabeth the lowercase characters are, but Im not really sure how to proceed.

**Code:**

```
# Filename: day01.py
# Author: S D
# License: http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License

# This class should do ROT24 on a string
#
# Examples:
#   A -> Y
#   a -> y
#   B -> Z
#   b -> z
#
# Special characters like { and } should not change

class Day01:

    access_code = '{JgkJqPå}'
    alphabeth_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå'
    alphabeth_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ'

    for access_code_character in access_code:
        # Lowercase find character number, a=1, b=2, c=3 etc
        x = 0;
        for find_char in alphabeth_lowercase:
            x = x+1
            if(find_char == access_code_character):
                print("Char " + str(access_code_character) + " is number " + str(x) + " in alpabeth")

                switch_with_number = x+24
```

**Output:**

```
Day 01
Char g is number 7 in alpabeth
Char k is number 11 in alpabeth
Char q is number 17 in alpabeth
Char å is number 29 in alpabeth

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `switch_with_number = (x+24)%len(alphabeth_lowercase)` and `new_char = alphabeth_lowercase[switch_with_number]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
ROT24_table = {'a': 'y', 'b': 'z', 'c': 'a', ...}
access_code = '{JgkJqPå}'
result = ''
for c in access_code:
    if c in ROT24_table:
        result += ROT24_table[c]
    else:
        result += c
print(result)
```

- you can generate `ROT24_table` with code, you don't need to do that manualy.
- This is a general find-and-replace algorithm, finding every letter in `ROT24_table.keys()` and replacing it with it's corosponding value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I manage to create with help from [inspectorG4dget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198633/inspectorg4dget) comment:

```
# Filename: day01.py
# Author: S D
# License: http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License

# This class should do ROT24 on a string
#
# Examples:
#   A -> Y
#   a -> y
#   B -> Z
#   b -> z
#
# Special characters like { and } should not change

class Day01:
    print('')
    print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Day 01 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')

    access_code = '{JgkJqPå}'
    alphabeth_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå'
    alphabeth_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ'
    solution = "";

    for access_code_character in access_code:
        character_found_in_lowercase_or_uppercase = "false";

        # Lowercase find character number, a=1, b=2, c=3 etc
        x = 0;
        for find_char in alphabeth_lowercase:
            x = x+1
            if(find_char == access_code_character):
                switch_with_number = (x + 26) % len(alphabeth_lowercase)
                new_char = alphabeth_lowercase[switch_with_number]
                print("Char " + str(access_code_character) + " -> " + str(new_char) + " -- char number " + str(x) + " in alpabeth, switch with number " + str(switch_with_number))

                solution = solution + str(new_char)
                character_found_in_lowercase_or_uppercase = "true";


        # Uppercase find character number, A=1, B=2, C=3 etc
        x = 0;
        for find_char in alphabeth_uppercase:
            x = x+1
            if(find_char == access_code_character):
                switch_with_number = (x + 26) % len(alphabeth_uppercase)
                new_char = alphabeth_uppercase[switch_with_number]
                print("Char " + str(access_code_character) + " -> " + str(new_char) + " -- char number " + str(x) + " in alpabeth, switch with number " + str(switch_with_number))

                solution = solution + str(new_char)
                character_found_in_lowercase_or_uppercase = "true";

        # Special characters
        if(character_found_in_lowercase_or_uppercase == "false"):
            print("Char " + str(access_code_character) + " -> " + str(access_code_character))

            solution = solution + str(access_code_character)


    print("Solution")
    print(str(access_code))
    print(str(solution))
```

Output:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Day 01 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Char { -> {
Char J -> H -- char number 10 in alpabeth, switch with number 7
Char g -> e -- char number 7 in alpabeth, switch with number 4
Char k -> i -- char number 11 in alpabeth, switch with number 8
Char J -> H -- char number 10 in alpabeth, switch with number 7
Char q -> o -- char number 17 in alpabeth, switch with number 14
Char P -> N -- char number 16 in alpabeth, switch with number 13
Char å -> æ -- char number 29 in alpabeth, switch with number 26
Char } -> }
Solution
{JgkJqPå}
{HeiHoNå}

Process finished with exit code 0
```